# Is there a way to limit the horizational flex of a fluid CSS layout?

Tags: css, website-design

**Example:**

Currently it does this: <-->

Want it to do this: <--|-|-->

**Meaning the core never gets smaller than say 900px, but the core stretches on forever if it's bigger than 900px. Note, currently it's a 3-column, and the sides are fixed, it's the center that grows.**

It's also be cool if I could control the max flex: |<--|-|-->|

**Meaning the page would not get smaller than 900x, but not larger than 1200px**

...so, maybe none of this is possible, or it's crazy easy -- but I've searched high and low for an example, or CSS specs on how to do this, and no luck so far.

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE:

---

Thanks to Dave, I was able to find a solution... :-) ...thanks Dave!!

[**Example of code**](http://friendlybit.com/files/min-max-template/)

```
#wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   width: expression(
      (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 962)? "960px" :
         (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 762)? "760px" :
            "auto"
   );
   height: 1%;
}
```

**-- OR here's the full HTML with inline JavaScript and CSS --**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Example of max- and min-width</title>
    <!-- You should of course use external CSS-files, not inline as I use in this example... -->
    <style type="text/css">
      #content {
        border: 1px solid red; /* For clarity, remove at will */
        max-width: 960px; /* Corresponds to 1024 with scrollbars */
        min-width: 760px; /* Corresponds to 800 with scrollbars */
        margin: 0 auto; /* Center the block */
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
      #content {
        height: 1%;
        width: 960px; /* Fallback width if javascript is off */
        width: expression(
          (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 962)? "960px" : 
            (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 762) ? "760px" : 
              "auto"
        );
      }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Example Content...</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**SOURCE:**  [Friendly Bit, Min-width and Max-width template](http://friendlybit.com/css/min-width-and-max-width-template/)

NOTE: Stack Exchange... Rocks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I got you wrong, but it seems you are looking for min-width and max-width properties.

Comment: you are not wrong.. that is what he is looking for :)

Comment: Cool, thanks... :-) ...you ROCK!! (+1 and selected as answer)

Comment: @Gaby: Thanks for the added confirmation, and the laugh... +1 ...cheers!

Comment: I'm glad to help. Thank you all for commenting and voting up :)

Comment: i think in your case its min-width.  Be careful with fluid layouts. I would not build a layout that could stretch 1000%.  I used to have multiple 30inch monitors, and if i opened a site in all of them that streched i would image it would get very weird.  Maybe do a max-width:1920; ??